# Using Spring Integration SftpInboundChannel In Conjunction With Spring Batch

Tags: spring-batch, spring-integration-sftp

### Problem description

Dear Stack-Overflow-Community,
I recently came across sftpinbound channel from Spring-Integration-Framework.

Is is possible to start the inbound channel by batch job or not?

### My tryouts until now

I already created a RunOnceTrigger and try to start its inbound-channel by job-request with the following code:

```
    @Bean
  @InboundChannelAdapter(channel = "fromSftpChannel",poller = @Poller(trigger = "fireSftpOnceTrigger"),autoStartup =
    "false")
  //@InboundChannelAdapter(channel = "fromSftpChannel", poller = @Poller(fixedRate = "1000"))
  public MessageSource<InputStream> sftpMessageSource() {
    SftpStreamingMessageSource messageSource = new SftpStreamingMessageSource(template());
    messageSource.setRemoteDirectory(sftpRemoteDirectoryDownload);
    messageSource.setFilter(new AcceptAllFileListFilter<>());
    messageSource.setMaxFetchSize(1);
    return messageSource;
  }
@Bean
  public IntegrationFlow flow() {
    return IntegrationFlows.from(Sftp.inboundStreamingAdapter(template())
          .filter(new AcceptAllFileListFilter<>())
          .remoteDirectory(sftpRemoteDirectoryDownload),
          e -> e.id("sftpinboundpoller").autoStartup(false).poller(Pollers.trigger(fireSftpOnceTrigger)))
      .channel(MessageChannels.queue("files"))
      .get();
  }
```

And finally I use this code to trigger my sftppoller but it seems only to trigger the sftp but not the file-read-job.

```
 SourcePollingChannelAdapterFactoryBean factoryBean =
      (SourcePollingChannelAdapterFactoryBean)flow().getIntegrationComponents().keySet().stream().findFirst().get();

    fireSftpOnceTrigger.reset();
    factoryBean.start();
```

Maybe someone is knowing a better way to start a sftp inbound channel by an batch job?

Best regards

Devron1705

Comment: What do you mean by "start the inbound channel by batch job"? Can you describe what you are trying to achieve without referring to Spring Integration or Spring Batch?

Comment: Simply without referring to Spring: I'd like to trigger a sftp-download by http-request and read the remote file content into db.

Comment: `trigger a sftp-download by http-request`: Spring Integration is a good candidate for this requirement. `read the remote file content into db`: Spring Batch is a good option for that. To connect the two, I invite you to check the documentation here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/reference/html/spring-batch-integration.html#launching-batch-jobs-through-messages

Answer (score 0):

## Looking at my errors

```
  @Bean
  public IntegrationFlow flow() {
    return IntegrationFlows.from(Sftp.inboundStreamingAdapter(template())
          .filter(new AcceptAllFileListFilter<>())
          .remoteDirectory(sftpRemoteDirectoryDownload),
          e -> e.id("sftpinboundpoller").autoStartup(false).poller(Pollers.trigger(fireSftpOnceTrigger)))
      **.channel(MessageChannels.queue("files"))**
      .get();
  }
```

**.channel(MessageChannels.queue("files"))** --> means queing my messages. I've created an channel called fromSftp that will transform the incoming-messages to an file-stream. Connection could be arranged by changing my previous codeline to **.channel(MessageChannels.direct("fromSftp"))** and its done.